# Stack Overflow sign in page wrong rendering on Firefox

Tags: support, design, firefox

When I try to sign in to Stack Overflow or another Stack Exchange service, it seems that css & javascripts are not loaded correct.

firefox 28.0
ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Cannot reproduce, can you check that the JS/CSS files are loading properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the page to render correctly, Javascript and CSS must be brought in from a third party Content Delivery Network (CDN). Chances are, the CDN sites are either blocked for you, or your browser isn't trusting their certificates.

In my situation, the problem was fixed by importing the certificate for
`cdn.sstatic.net`. There are other CDNs in the Stack Exchange network, so you
may need others depending on what site(s) you're using (e.g.,
`sstatic.stackexchange.netdna-cdn.com`, etc.).

You can read more about this problem, troubleshooting tips, and possible
solutions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85454/269610) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97663/intermittent-responses-from-cdn/100102#100102).